# Ruby % operator

Tags: ruby, string

I'm having trouble understanding what the following code snippet is doing

```
"foo = %{foo}" % { :foo => 'bar' }
=> "foo = bar"
```

so from the understanding the "foo = %{foo}" is the format specification but in this instance it appears to perform variable interpolation with the %{foo}?

Comment: Wish the example snippet was better; the left foo confused me for sometime. If possible try to  change it to something else, it might make the snippet more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) uses the given string as a format specification, and apply argument (array / hash) and return the resulting string.

`%{...}` is reference by name formatting. There's also `%<...>` which also need format style (s, d, f, ...)

```
"foo = %{key}" % { :key => 'bar' }
# => "foo = bar"
"foo = %<key>s" % { :key => 'bar' }
# => "foo = bar"
```

For more detail about format specification, see [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Answer (score 2):

The [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) of `String#%` refers to [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

At the end of `sprintf`'s doc you'll find a brief explanation of two types of substitution that use names (with a hash argument) instead of positions (with an array argument).

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of interpreting something like this is to look at the first part of the line, which is a string literal (`foo = %{foo}`), the % sign thus means the % method of String ([String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25)), so the literal is in fact the first part of a format specification, how the string is presented. The part after the % has to be an array or a hash, in this case a hash which does a named substitution, meaning that the `key` is the is the name of the key that has to be present in the hash, returning the value `bar`

You could write this with normal substitution but then you need two lines of code.

```
hash = { :key => 'bar' }
"foo = #{hash[:key]}"
```

Or just using a variable

```
foo = "bar"
"foo = #{foo}"
```

Which if nothing else is involved is much more readable.